# Why the definitions fail to be displayed in this schema?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to develop a schema compliant with the swagger specifications. See below. The definitions(model/schema) of the Parameters and Responses are not displayed in the swagger-ui interface so my question why is that. The schema passes the swagger validator.

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "example",
    "description": "provides  various stuff",
    "termsOfService": "none",
    "contact": {
      "name": "admin",
      "url": "http://www.example.co.uk",
      "email": "hostmaster@example.com"
    },
    "license": {
      "name": "All Rights Reserved.",
      "url": "http://example.com"
    }
  },
  "host": "ofexample.co.uk",
  "basePath": "/",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/list": {
      "post": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "no_name",
            "in": "body",
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#definitions/APIName"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#definitions/Versions"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/ver/setdefault": {
      "post": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "no_name",
            "in": "body",
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#definitions/App"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#definitions/App"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "APIName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "App": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "object",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/APIName",
          "description": "\n The name"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "important field"
        },
        "version": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "Versions": {
      "type": "string",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spec itself is almost right, only part that's off is the `$ref`. There needs to be a `/` between the `#` and the `definitions/APIName` for example.

```
      {
        "name": "no_name",
        "in": "body",
        "required": false,
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/APIName"
        }
      }
```

Note the UI will not show no referenced primitives due to a bug. Defining it inline for the parameter will show it properly, but for the response it won't.

Another note, while now it is not well defined, if there's no `consumes`/`produces`, the mime type that will be used is `application/json`. If you want to use text, you may want to set it to be `text/plain` to pass around strings.